# how to edited values in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

following is my view model

```
var Patientp = function () {
    this.id = ko.observable(idValue);
    this.name = ko.observable(nameValue);
    this.degree = ko.observable(degreeValue);
    this.gender = ko.observable(genderValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observableArray(consultantArrValue);
    this.username = ko.observable(usernameValue);
    this.password = ko.observable(passwordValue);
    this.email = ko.observable(emailValue);
    this.mobile = ko.observable(mobileValue);    
    this.imgFile = ko.observable(imgFileValue);
    this.imgSrc = ko.observable(imgSrcValue);
    this.imagePath=ko.observable(imagePathValue); 
    this.userid=ko.observable(useridValue); 
    this.department=ko.observable(departmentValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observableArray(consultantArrValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observable(consultantValue);


}
```

I am getting input from a ajax call as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: projectUrl+"getDoctors",  
    dataType:"json",
    jsonp: true,
    async:false ,
    success: function (data) {
        //alert(data);
        $.each(data.doctors, function(index, currPat) {
            var doc = new Doctor(currPat.name,currPat.username);
            doctors.push(doc);
            if(currPat.userid=="${IDis}"){
           console.log(currPat.degree); 
           nameValue = currPat.name;
           usernameValue =currPat.username;
           passwordValue ="" ;
           emailValue = currPat.email;
           mobileValue = currPat.mobile;
           genderValue = currPat.gender;
           departmentValue=currPat.department;
           degreeValue=currPat.degree;
           imgSrcValue=currPat.imagePath;
            }
       });    
      }
});
```

Now all the input fields has old values.Now I want to change some input fields and after when I press the save button I want values in JSON so that I can pass in ajax format.so I am using ko.toJSON like below

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
    alert('savebutton');
    var testjson=ko.toJSON(new Patientp());
    console.log(testjson);

});
```

**Please see the screenshot,the mobile value is 1234567890**

[image]

**now I made mobile to 666 and pressed save button,see the mobile(JSON in console) is still unchanged**

[image]
But here I am only getting the old values.Can any body please tell me how to get the new values(what ever I type in the input fields)

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your requirement, can you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani see the 1st screenshot shows the datas that I am getting from ajax(when the page is loaded) and it gets printed in the input field.Now I changed mobile number from 1234567890 to 666 AND pressed save button.see the JSON now in the console,the value is not unchanged.But when I press the save button then I want the values.Hope you understand

Comment: Can you please show the HTML that has your data binding?  Could you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468297/how-to-add-datas-from-json-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing 2 time `new Patientp()` once in `ko.applyBindings(new Patientp())` and another time `var testjson=ko.toJSON(new Patientp());`

now when I did 
`var patp=new Patientp();` and after that `ko.applyBindings(patp)` and `var testjson=ko.toJSON(patp);` then the problem is solved